# When does the PostgreSQL JDBC driver fetch rows after executing a query?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

When does the [PostgreSQL JDBC driver](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/) version [9.2-1002](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/changes.html#version_9.2-1002) fetch rows from the server after executing a query?  Does it fetch the rows immediately after query execution (after the client application invokes [`PreparedStatement.executeQuery()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29)) or after the client application first invokes [`ResultSet.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) to retrieve a row from the result set?  Does this depend on the value of the statement fetch size?

Comment: Why would you care? Or put otherwise: why would anyone call `executeQuery` and *not* call `next()` immediately after that?

Comment: I'm trying to separate the time it takes to execute a query from the time it takes to fetch the rows and process the result set.  Does query execution time include the time to fetch the rows or does result set processing include the fetch time?

Comment: I think the best way to test this is to write a simple program, start a debugger, add some breakpoints and watch the traffic via wireshark (or a similar tool).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the following program demonstrates, `PreparedStatement.executeQuery()` always retrieves rows in the result set from the server.  The program also demonstrates how statement fetch size impacts row retrieval.  In the case where the statement has the default fetch size of zero, `executeQuery()` retrieves all rows from the server and `ResultSet.next()` retrieves and returns the next row from memory, not from the server.  (The program may even close the connection after executing the query and `next()` can still iterate over all rows.)  In the case where fetch size is non-zero, `executeQuery()` retrieves the first batch of rows, the number of which equals the fetch size, and `ResultSet.next()` again returns the next row from memory until it consumes all rows in the current batch, at which point it retrieves the next batch of rows from the server.  This pattern repeats until `ResultSet.next()` retrieves an empty batch from the server (one that contains zero rows).

**SQL**

```
-- Create table "test" and insert 2,000,000 integers from 1 up to 2,000,000.
WITH RECURSIVE t(n) AS
(
  VALUES (1)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n+1
  FROM t
  WHERE n < 2000000
)
SELECT n as value
INTO test
FROM t;
```

**Java**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Start
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException, SQLException
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName( "org.postgresql.Driver" );
        }
        catch ( ClassNotFoundException e )
        {
            System.out.println( "Where is your JDBC Driver?" );
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        System.out.println( "Registered JDBC driver" );
        Connection connection = null;

        try
        {
            final String databaseUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5483/postgres";
            final Properties properties = new Properties();
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection( databaseUrl, properties );
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

            // Default fetch size of 0 does not create a cursor.
            // Method executeQuery will retrieve all rows in result set.
            statement.setFetchSize( 0 );

            // Fetch size of 1 creates a cursor with batch size of 1.
            // Method executeQuery will retrieve only 1 row in the result set.
            //statement.setFetchSize( 1 );

            System.out.println( new Date() + ": Before execute query" );
            ResultSet result =
                statement.executeQuery( "select * from test" );
            System.out.println( new Date() + ": After execute query" );
            System.out.println( new Date() + ": Sleep for 5 s" );
            Thread.sleep( 5000 );
            System.out.println( new Date() + ": Before process result set" );
            while ( result.next() );
            System.out.println( new Date() + ": After process result set" );
            result.close();
            statement.close();
        }
        catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            System.out.println( "Connection failed!" );
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            if ( connection != null )
                connection.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can [set the fetchsize in jdbc](http://webmoli.com/2009/02/01/jdbc-performance-tuning-with-optimal-fetch-size/)

Answer (score 3):

Look at this [documentation](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor)

> **By default the driver collects all the results for the query at once.** This can be inconvenient for large data sets so the JDBC driver provides a means of basing a ResultSet on a database cursor and only fetching a small number of rows.
>
> A small number of rows are cached on the client side of the connection and when exhausted the next block of rows is retrieved by repositioning the cursor.

Further [read this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-single-row-mode.html)

> Ordinarily, libpq collects a SQL command's entire result and returns it to the application as a single PGresult. This can be unworkable for commands that return a large number of rows. For such cases, applications can use PQsendQuery and PQgetResult in single-row mode. In this mode, the result row(s) are returned to the application one at a time, as they are received from the server.

Comment: This doesn't tell me exactly when the driver fetches the results from the server.  Does the driver retrieve the results when the client application invokes `PreparedStatement.executeQuery()` or only after the first invocation of `ResultSet.next()` or one of the other result set navigation methods?

Comment: @DerekMahar If you want to know exactly when, then you need to look at the source of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver.

Comment: The driver caches requests rows in `fetchSize` quantities. Each time you request an additional row beyond what is cached `fetchSize` rows are requests until the result set is exhausted.You can modify `fetchSize` via http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize%28int%29

Comment: PgJDBC isn't actually based on `libpq`, so the second quote isn't really relevant. Just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

PG requires the connection to be AutoCommit = false for getting rows as cursor.
So if you use Spring jdbc and TransactionManagement you can use connection from Transaction, which has AutoCommit = false by default.

```
@Repository()
public class SampleRepoImpl implements SampleRepo {

    private static final String SQL = "select s.id from generate_series(1,100000) as s(id)";

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public void findAsCursor(RecordProcessor recordProcessor) throws SQLException {

        // It shouldn't close by hands, it will when the transaction finished.
        Connection connection = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);

        try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)) {
            ps.setFetchSize(100);
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    long id = rs.getLong("id");
                    System.out.println("id = " + id);
    }}}}}
```