# Get data by chunks with Prepared statement

Tags: java, postgresql, prepared-statement

I have PostgreSQL  db and I need to use prepared statement in java to get the data. I read that the results set load all the results to the memory, how can I load the results by chunks while using prepared statement?

Thanks,

Comment: have a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475105/when-does-the-postgresql-jdbc-driver-fetch-rows-after-executing-a-query)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: stament.setFetchSize(0) fetches all rows to memory, stament.setFetchSize(100) fetches only 100 rows to memory and after reading 100 rows when you request a row (by resultset.next()) another 100 rows fetched to memory

Comment: See the manual: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor